# Primes being a square sum of an odd number and a less number

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

For natural numbers $a,b$, let $a$ be odd and let $f(a)$ be the number of $\,b<a\,$ such that $a^2+b^2$ is prime. In the diagram $f$ is blue, the function $g(n)=\frac{n}{\ln n}$ is red and $h(n)=\frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\frac{n}{\ln n}$ is green.

Since the blue curve is nearly limited by the red and the green curves it seems reasonable to make the conjecture:

> There are real numbers $A$ and $B$ such that  $A\cdot\frac{n}
> {\ln n}<f(n)<B\cdot\frac{n}{\ln n}$, where $n$ is odd.

[image]

What would be the intuition behind this?

Comment: Other than plotting, have you tried proving it analytically? For instance, what happens if you combine [Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) with the [Prime Number Theorem for arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime_number_theorem_for_arithmetic_progressions)?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire - Thanks for the tip that somehow explain the intuition, even if I can't manage the details!